# Optimizing mathematical index calculation function

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, pawn

I have made a function which calculates the index of a point to which an arbitrary point on a polygon made of XY points belong.

This is a visual representation:

[image]

And this is the function I made:

```
stock GetNodeIndexFromPolygonIndex(polygonid,Polygon_Size)
{
    new polid = (polygonid - (polygonid % 2));
    new mid = Polygon_Size/2;
    if(polid > mid)
    {
        polid /= 2;
        return (mid - (++polid));
    }
    else
    {
        polid /= 2;
        if(polid == 0)
        {
            return 0;
          }
        return --polid;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can optimize here?  This function is going to be called ~2000 times in the worst case in one run on a single threaded application. I would like this to be as optimal as possible.  Is it already?

Comment: I personally don't understand the explanation. Why 3 in the first red circle for example?

Comment: The basic thing is thhat the red circles are a PATH which is created from XYZ points and have indexes from 0 to up. yet, there is a polygon around it which has to be closed so one polygon point has 4 indexes (XY, XY, first and last polygon point). The black points are thus the polygon around the red path with a specific width. Just like here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/x865n.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I do not know anything about PAWN.

Does it have a profiler? Can any profiler be used? If yes, probably use it.
If no, write at least some test units to measure execution time.

I will assume typical language elements. I will assume `polygonid > 0` and `Polygon_Size > 0`, because I do not know (and did not find in short time) the behavior of `/` and `%` for negative numbers.

As far as I understood, there is a virtual machine between compiler and execution. This makes things a little bit more complex, but well, we will assume that nothing special happens there.

Some of the optimizations could change nothing, because the compiler already does it. I can not predict or test it.

That said, I will choose line after line. I do not know if you can change the algorithm, because like Cygal I do not understand the exact purpose.

---

```
new polid = (polygonid - (polygonid % 2));
```

This makes polid the next smallest even number? `%` is rather costly, you could either do a `polygonid & 1` instead of `polygonid % 2` or `new polid = polygonid & (max_value - 1)` which will set all bits, but the last one to zero. max_value - 1 should be precalculated.

---

```
new mid = Polygon_Size/2;
```

Change to: `new mid = Polygon_Size >> 1` This will be done most probably by the compiler anyway, but we do not know, so lets try it.

---

```
polid /= 2;
```

This is calculated in both branches. It could help to do it before the branching:

```
new polid_half = polid >> 1;
...
```

---

```
return (mid - (++polid));
```

This depends on the language details. It could be that `++polid` as preincrement operator will load polid, update it by one, and store polid back. We do not plan to use the modified polid, so we could try `return (mid - polid + 1)` assuming that `++polid` is not some magic fast special instruction compared to the normal `+`.

---

```
    if(polid == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

This does only happen if polygonid is 0 or 1. If this happens a lot, you should return immediately at the beginning, saving all the rest:

```
if (polygonid < 2 )  //assuming polygonid > 0
    return 0;
```

And remove the check inside the else branch.

---

```
    return --polid;
```

Same as before, it could be better to `return polid - 1`

---

Depending on the branch prediction handling, it could be better to have only one return point, not one in every branch. You could introduce a return value and set it according to the current logic.

---

I would try one change after the next and profile every step. All together, it could be:

```
stock GetNodeIndexFromPolygonIndex(polygonid,Polygon_Size)
{
    if (polygonid < 2 )  //assuming polygonid > 0
        return 0;
    new result = 0;
    new polid = polygonid & (max_value - 1); //polid is a bad name
    new polid_half = polid >> 1;
    new mid = Polygon_Size >> 1;
    if(polid > mid)
        result = mid - polid_half + 1;
    else
        result = polid_half - 1;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Another caveat: those micro-optimizations make the code way less readable, but since it's probably the only thing to do, here's an upvote for you. :)

Comment: @Cygal Well, the `>> 1` are probably too much and some `if-else` braces would also increase readability.